# End of Ame Agaru

Tags: plot-explanation, ending, after-the-rain

I just watched [*After the Rain* (1999)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0181960/), or *Ame agaru* (original title), and I don't really understand the end of the film. The Lord of the fief was supposed to catch Misawa, to accept him as Master-of-Arms. But he didn't! The film ended just before that. How should I understand that? Do you have any explanations?

Comment: @all For now I tagged this `after-the-rain`, see [this relevant meta question](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/975/49) for a possibility to discuss this matter.

Comment: @ChristianRau, thanks! I have 2 questions: 1) will you create tag for each film? Isn't this overwhelming? 2) the linked question argues for original title of the film, [which is "Ame Agaru"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0181960/) in this case.

Comment: Yes, the general policy is a tag for each movie. Of course this will produce many tags, but it helps to easily identify the topic of a question and to search for certain movie questions (and well, tags don't really cost anybody anything, no?). And the linked question doesn't have much of an opnion on the matter (it only argues about English original titles vs. English alternative titles). The existing answer addresses the tagging problem with non-English original titles but only says that it's not completely clear what to do, while a comment argues for the English title...

Comment: ...So you see it's not a decided discussion yet and I invite you to bring in your own views into it by writing an answer to this meta-question.

Comment: @ChristianRau thanks, and yes now it seems reasonable to create tag for each film. Maybe another tag "ame-agaru" should be created and declared as a synonyme?

Comment: This might actually be not such a bad idea as a general solution. I'll see what the mods and community think about it.

Comment: @ChristianRau yes, we have tag synonymes - why not to use them? This is the exact situation when it comes in handy.

Comment: @Tomas & ChristianRau  related meta discussion http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/977/movie-name-tag-should-be-of-original-title-or-english-title